# asp.net peer to peer chat application

Tags: asp.net, chat

I want to create an asp.net chat application and now I have two choices:

1. Using TCP/IP connection and creating peer to peer connection between chatters.
2. Using Database to store the chats text and use Ajax to create communication between the chatters.

Which one look like good solution or do have any solution?

Comment: I think , now days both the solution are odd

Comment: **I think**..... this is opinion absed so its off-topic for SO...

Comment: @Zaibis I am not sure. It may still be off-topic, because it is relatively open and little research seems to have gone into this. But I can not see this being opinion based. The wording of the last sentence suggests it is, but basically the asker describes a problem and wants to know if two solutions he/she came up with are workable.

Comment: @Wutz The last sentence is his only question so dunno maybe im wrong, but for me is asking for "whats better in my case" opinon based

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you intend to have your chat used in a browser, since that has different requirements than if you wanted to supply a webview to embed in a native application you are developing.

Solution 1 is not really an option. You can't establish direct p2p-connections in a browser, at least not without java/flash/plugins.

Solution 2 could work, although you don't necessarily need a database. Unless you want to save a chatlog or supply offline messages, you can simply cache recent messages on the server. When a message is more than a few minutes old, you can likely assume it to be of no interest any more. Depending on your needs ofc.

Another very interesting solution is websockets. Websockets basically provide an interface for live communication with the browser, so that clients do not need to poll for messages using ajax, but can simply hold open a connection to your server, wich supplies updates (=new messages) as they become available.

Since WebSockets are not universally supported yet (although firefox, chrome and mobile devices in general offer very good support nowadays) you should probably set up an ajax interface as a fallback for older browsers. Other than that, I think WebSockets are your best option.